# Calculate Matrix: walkSpeed parameter for pedestrian routes

Tags: here-api

I'm trying to get a travel time matrix for pedestrians and used `Calculate Matrix` with `mode='fastest;pedestrian'`.

The resulting travel times are not realistic as `walkSpeed=1` is assumed (wego.here.com uses `walkSpeed=1.4` and returns results that are consistent with other route planners such as Google Maps). Setting the `walkSpeed` parameter in the request only works for `Calculate Route`, but has no effect for `Calculate Matrix`.

Thus, I have two questions:

- Is it possible to change the `walkSpeed` in the matrix request?
- If not: can I simply divide pedestrian travel times by 1.4 or would that
  result in wrong/suboptimal results?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `walkspeed` is not supported by the `calculatematrix` API as supported in the `calculateroute` API. Dividing the results by `1.4` may not give optimal results so we cannot recommend that. We can suggest this as a feature request for a later release if you would like that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. This feature would certainly be useful in the future.